# Azure SQL - Sudden connection spike

Tags: security, sql, azure

**At first:**

This is my first question on Serverfault. I am not sure if it fits better on Information Security.  If so, please leave a comment and I will move the question.

**Question**

My company is developing on Azure for one of our customers.
We run a cloud-app with a SQL-Server.
The company is very small and normal.y there are around 3-10 connections but today we had a huge spike of connections. 
Is it something I have to be worried about?
Was someone accessing my server illegally?

[image: connection spike]

Comment: SQL Server or SQL Azure?

Comment: SQL Database in the Azure Cloud.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start with the application. Azure SQL works with white list by default so it's unlikely someone accessed your database directly.

Most probable scenario would be bots (malicious or not) that found your web server and started to crawl. They usually works for a small amount of time and leave.

Check web server access logs (filter date/time period) and analyze the incoming requests for suspicious data. If you are using Azure Websites, unfortunately you wont have it enabled by default so there will be no data to look for.

**Enable diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App Service**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/